# How to enable multiline logs instead of single-line progress-logs

Tags: makefile, cmake

Here is a sample output of my cmake:

> 2017/10/27 07:51:46 Platform overridden to 'RHEL5_64'
>   -- **cmake version: 3.2.3**
>   -- Configuring done
>   -- Generating done
>   -- Build files have been written to: /local/home/etc
>   **[3/3] Linking CXX shared library libsample_z.so**

The last line actually shows progress (as indicated by **[3/3]**) and thus overwritten in-place; so I cannot see all the logs (i.e the messages correspond to **[1/3]** and **[2/3]**). I want cmake to print all logs to stay on its own line, like:

> Linking CXX shared library libsample_x.so
>   Linking CXX shared library libsample_y.so
>   Linking CXX shared library libsample_z.so

What can be done in cmake to log like this?

Comment: Do you use `ninja`? I had the same problem with `ninja`.

Comment: I think *yes*, because I see **"ninja: no work to do"** when no build is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" with `ninja` is, that it [automatically detects](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/blob/94fc14314501a78b1742e910f7c920188b2753da/src/line_printer.cc#L59) if you are running from a shell where it can replace the progress output in line. And there are - as of October 2017 - no command line switches or environment variables to change this behavior.

Since it checks for the console's output buffer, I found that piping the output on my Windows console somewhere else does show multi-line outputs again. So i used the following pipe command:

```
cmake -G "Ninja" ..
cmake --build . > CON
```

*NOTE*: That will only work if you don't have this call inside a script that needs the `stdout` output itself again for piping it e.g. into a log file. Meaning the output is no longer on `stdout` after this pipe command.

Comment: If you DO want to see output on stdout (seems obvious), use `cmake --build . | tee /dev/null` where dev/null can be name of file that will contain output as well. This usually disables color output (from compiler warnings etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the accept answer, another option is to tick ninja into not seeing the terminal by piping to cat.

```sh
ninja | cat -
```

This will get you multi line output, but you will loose any console coloring as well.

Answer (score 0):

From `man ninja`:

```
-v     show all command lines while building
```

Comment: no, this will show *content* of all commands but not *comments*